# Java snippet that causes stack overflow in the compiler or typechecker (javac)?

Tags: java, covariance, stack-overflow, contravariance, typechecking

Yesterday at a seminar the presenter (Peter Sestoft) showed a small java program, with 3 classes, featuring both co-variance and contra-variance. When attempting to compile using javac, the type checker will throw a StackOverflowException.

The snippet is developed by some guys that work at Microsoft (think one was called Kennedy).

Can't find it using Google. Does anyone know the code snippet, and could you paste it here (it's max. 10 lines of code), for everyone to see? :)

It was quite fun...

Comment: ... and it may be necessary to know the exact version of the javac that shows that behavior.

Comment: You are looking for this paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/FOOL2007.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it (asked the presenter)! It's a `StackOverflowException` in both 6.0 and 7.0:

```
class T { }
class N<Z> { }
class C<X> extends N<N<? super C<C<X>>>> {
  N<? super C<T>> cast(C<T> c) { return c; }
}
```

It's from Andrew Kennedy and Benjamin Pierce: On Decidability of Nominal
 Subtyping with Variance.  International Workshop on Foundations and
 Developments of Object-Oriented Languages g(FOOL/WOOD'07), Nice,
 France 2007.

Comment: ofc it may not cause a StackOverflowException on a machine with infinite storage, but that was implied. Don't know if that is the case or not.

Comment: Cool. May it happen in "real life" — with "real" code that has a meaning?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the Java Bug Database at [bugs.java.com](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/)? Here's a `StackOverflowError` in 5.0 only:

```java
import java.util.*;

class Test<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    abstract class Group<E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
    extends ArrayList<E> 
    implements Comparable<Group<? extends E>> {}

    abstract class Sequence<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
    extends TreeSet<E>
    implements Comparable<Sequence<? extends E>> {}

    public void containsCombination(SortedSet<Group<T>> groups,
                    SortedSet<Sequence<T>> sequences) {
        foo(groups, sequences);
    }

    <C extends Collection<T>> void foo(SortedSet<? extends C> setToCheck,
                       SortedSet<? extends C> validSet) {}

}
```

Here's another (again 5.0 only):

```java
class F<T> {}
class C<X extends F<F<? super X>>> {
    C(X x) {
        F<? super X> f = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice examples, especially the second one. But the one I'm looking for fails in both 6.0 and 7.0. I can't quite remember it, but I'd recognize it if I saw it again :)